# When is $k^4-24k+16$ a perfect square.

Tags: factoring, square-numbers

When is the equation $k^4-24k+16$ perfect square.
(k is an  integer.)

I got this equation as discriminant while solving an equation. I tried to solve it but couldn't i tried to write it in a form of a square but couldnt solve it.I bashed a bit and found 0 and 3 as a solution. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: also $k=-3$ makes the *expression* a perfect square

Comment: Can you prove, for $k>11$, $k^2-1<\sqrt{k^4-24k+16}<k^2$?  and, for $k<-12$, $k^2<\sqrt{k^4-24k+16}<k^2+1$?  Then there are only a few cases left to check

Comment: I emphasized *expression*, because $k^4-24k+16$ is an expression, not an equation

Answer (score 3):

For $k\ge 12$, it can be shown that $(k^2-1)^2\lt k^4-24k+16<(k^2)^2$.

For $k\le-13$, it can be shown that $(k^2)^2\lt k^4-24k+16 < (k^2+1)^2$.

Thus, $k^4-24k+16$ cannot be a perfect square unless

$k\in \{-12,-11,-10,-9,-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11\}$.

Of the elements of that finite set, $k^4-24k+16$ is a perfect square only for $k=-3, 0, $ and $3$.

Comment: It's very impressive that you typed out $-12$ to $11$. +1

Comment: Lol ;-)  @WhatsUp

Comment: Congrats. Its cool that you soved it. But would you please mind revealing your thought process and your efforts. How you realised what you needed to solve this question.

Comment: I realized, as @Angina Seng also pointed out, that, for large $k$, $\sqrt{k^4-24k+16}$ will be close to but not equal to $k^2$ (and so won't be an integer).  I then made a table of $\sqrt{k^4-24k+16}$ and saw that, for $k>11$ and for $k<-12$, $|\sqrt{k^4-24k+16}-k^2|<1$, and then saw that I could prove that is the case for $k\ge12$ and for $k\le-13$

Answer (score 1):

For large $k$, $a=\sqrt{k^4-24k+16}$ will be very close to, but not equal to $k^2$
(and so won't be an integer). How close?
$$|k^2-a|=\frac{|k^4-a^2|}{k^2+a}=\frac{|24k-16|}{k^2+a}\le\frac{|24k-16|}{k^2}.$$
If $|k|\ge 25$, then
$$|24k-16|\le24|k|+16<25|k|\le k^2$$
and so $|k^2-a|<1$. So we only need check $k$ between $-24$ and $24$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a refinement of the answers of Angina Seng, J. W. Tanner, and JCAA, using parity (even/odd) to reduce the amount of checking.

Since $-24k+16$ is even, $k^4-24k+16$ has the same parity as $k$.  Thus if $k\ne 0$ and $k^4-24k+16$ is a square, it is either $(k^2-2)^2$ or smaller or $(k^2+2)^2$ or larger.

Suppose first $k$ is positive.  If $(k^2-2)^2 < k^4-24k+16$, we see that $k^4-24k+16$ cannot be a square.  This inequality simplifies to $-4k^2+4<-24k+16$, which further simplifies to $6k<k^2+3$.  This is true as long as $k\ge 6$, so we only need to check $k=1,2,3,4,5$.  Only $k=3$ works.

A similar argument shows we only need to check $k$ from $-6$ to $-1$ for $k$ negative.  Only $k=-3$ works.

Comment: Would you mind explaining that $(k-2)^2$ and $(k+2)^2$ part, the larger and smaller one.

Comment: To Math enthusiast: Let's say $k$ is positive.  Then $k^4-24k+16<k^4$, so if it's a perfect square, it has to be the square of something less than $k^2$.  Because of parity, it can't be the square of $k^2-1$, so it must be the square of $k^2-2$ or something smaller.  The argument shows that if $k\ge 6$, then $(k^2-2)^2<k^4-24k+16$, so $k^4-24k+16$ cannot be the square of anything.
When $k$ is negative, $k^4-24k+16 > k^4$, so we look at $(k^2+2)^2$, since $(k^2+1)^2=k^4-24k+16$ is impossible by parity.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a correct solution. Suppose that $k^4-24k+16$ is a square.

1. Suppose that $-24k+16\ge 0$. Then $k^4-24k+16\ge (k^2+1)^2=k^4+2k^2+1$, so $-24k+16\ge 2k^2+1$ or $2k^2+24k-15\le 0$ or $k^2+12k-7.5\le 0$. This means $$-6-\sqrt{36+7.5}\le k\le -6+\sqrt{36+7.5}.$$

Which means $-13\le k\le 0$ (remember that $-24k+16>0$). Checking all these $k$ we get that only $k=-3,0$ are good.

2. Suppose that $-24k+16<0$ (in particular $k\ge 0$). Then $k^4-24k+16\le (k^2-1)^2=k^4-2k^2+1$, so $2k^2-24k+15\le 0$, or $k^2-12k+7.5\le 0$. Thus $6-\sqrt{36-7.5} \le k\le 6+\sqrt{36-7.5}$. So $1\le k\le 11$. Checking all these $k$, we get $k=3$.

Thus there are three possibilities: $k=-3,0,3$.

Comment: Did you mean $k>0$ when you typed $k\ge0$?

Comment: Where? If it is in part 2, then it does not matter because eventually $k\ge 1$ anyway.

Comment: Yes, $-24k+16$ is not equivalent to $k\ge0$

Comment: You made a misprint in your comment. It should be $-24k+16<0$. I should not have written "equivalent". But this does not matter.

Comment: I meant $-24k+16<0$ is not equivalent to $k\ge0$

Comment: Replaced "equivalent" by "in particular".

Answer (score 0):

Let's write the expression as $k^4 - 24k + 16 = (k^2 \pm 4)^2 = k^4 \pm 8k^2+16$.

Given the first and last term are same in both, the second term has to be equal for it to be perfect square which leads to -

$\pm8k^2 = -24k \implies k (k \pm 3) = 0$ which gives $k = 0, -3, 3$.